# Run Cron job at specific time

Tags: python-3.x, cron

I have python script that must be run on a crontab.
Here is my config
[image]

Here is the content of my fastq.sh

```
pipenv run python Main.py
```

But nothing happen,
Someone have an idea?
Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by following this steps:
1-I edited Main.py and added this code 
`!/usr/bin/env python3`

as first line.
2- Transform Main.py as an executable by using this command `chmod u+x Main.py`
3- Add this line in the crontab `6 17,18 * * * /usr/bin/env python3 /home/robot/bin/LUXIA/Main.py`

Comment: first two are not necessary, only third one was helpful